# Ubuntu machine stuck in black screen after using a usb stick

Tags: boot, usb, reboot

I used a usb stick on a windows machine in a random laptop, and I used same usb stick in my laptop.. I started getting messages like "you have insufficient privileges" and then I couldn't open all my installed web browsers.. and I decided to restart the machine, and now it is stuck in a black screen
I don't know what I should do now..
Can you help?